# How to configure Babel (or a Babel plugin) to automatically transform a directory import to a file inside the directory?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

When writing React components, I find myself adopting this directory style for when a component needs supporting files (CSS modules, images, etc.):

```
src/components/Simple.jsx
src/components/Complex/Complex.jsx
src/components/Complex/Complex.module.scss
src/components/Complex/otherExampleSupportFile.js
```

With the main component in a file named the same as the directory (because if the main code always in the directory `index.jsx`, all the code editor tabs will all say "index", and that would get confusing fast).

But then this requires a small `src/components/Complex/index.js` file containing `export default from './Complex';` if anyone wants to attempt to import Complex from `src/components/Complex`, in the same way they import `src/components/Simple`. This workaround allows the imports to work, but adds extra stub modules into the build.

**How would I go about configuring Babel (or a Babel plugin) to transform imports like this:**

```
import Complex from 'src/components/Complex';
```

**into this:**

```
import Complex from 'src/components/Complex/Complex';
```

**when the target path is a directory (and doesn't contain any `index.js` / `index.jsx` files)?**

So for example, given these files:

```
src/components/Complex/Complex.jsx
src/components/Manual/index.jsx
src/components/Simple.jsx
```

And these imports:

```
import Complex from 'src/components/Complex';
import Manual from 'src/components/Manual';
import Simple from 'src/components/Simple';
```

Babel would transpile to something like this (not including the `_interopRequireDefault` wrappers):

```
var Complex = require('src/components/Complex/Complex.jsx');
// and these would remain unchanged from Babel's current behaviour…
var Manual = require('src/components/Manual/index.jsx');
var Simple = require('src/components/Simple.jsx');
```

Comment: are you using export default?

Comment: @BrandonKnight Yes, all files have a default export matching their filename